# Android Webview app not downloading successful

Tags: java, android, webview

My Android app has a Webview to access to my website. I noticed in the server that when a file is downloaded by the app the bandwidth used is less than when is downloaded by another device or browser.

In method onDownloadStart I call to an AsyncTask class:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]); 

        //Getting directory to store the file

        //Connection handler
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        //Obtaining filename

        File outputFile = new File(directory, filename);
        InputStream input   = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        int total = 0;
        while ((bufferLength=input.read(buffer))!=-1) {
            total += bufferLength;
            output.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }             
        connection.disconnect();
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Files downloaded are empty altough their filename and format are correct and I receive HTTP 200 message from the server; also execution does not enter into the while loop. I have tried to change buffer size and the problem is not solved.